# JQuery .Param convert list object to querystring incorrect in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am preparing an array of sending data in Javascript and send to ASP.Net MVC by href. The array object has been serialize as Query Parameter as JQuery.Param(...), it can generate query parameters but I am not sure it's correct. After that, I make an href URL with query parameter and send to ASP.Net MVC action.

Javascript

```
    var sendData = { data: [{ Id: 1, IsLevel1: true, IsLevel2: true }] };
    var recursiveEncoded = $.param(sendData);

    var href = '@Url.Action("Report", "Home")?' + recursiveEncoded;
    window.location.href = href;
```

ASP.Net MVC

```
    public ActionResult Report(Models.ReportRequest[] data)
    {
        // Handle list of received data
        return null;
    }
```

I have send a data with Id=1, IsLevel1 is 'true', IsLevel2 is 'true'
But the real received by ASP.Net MVC just a list with default value Id=0, IsLevel=false, IsLevel2=false (Amount of items is enough but data incorrect)

[image]

Is anyone has experience on this issue?

Comment: You can access the query string as NameValueCollection by using `Request.QueryString` in the Report action method.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to send **post data** in **window.location.href**, even if it is possible, it is not a good practice to do so.

Instead create a form **(probably hidden)** updated the parameter fields, then submit. Please add post url in the form tag.